# Display message when no match found in AWK

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I'm writing a small BASH script that reads a csv file with names on it and prompts the user for a name to be removed. The csv file looks like this:

```
Smith,John
Jackie,Jackson
```

The first and last name of the person to be removed from the list are saved in the bash variables `$first_name` and `$last_name.`

This is what I have so far:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F',' -v last="$last_name" -v first="$first_name" ' ($1 != last || $2 != first) { print } ' > tmpfile1
```

This works fine. However, it still outputs to `tmpfile1` even if no employee matches that name. What I would like is to have something like:

```
if ($1 != last || $2 != first) { print }  > tmpfile1 ; else { print "No Match Found." }
```

I'm new to awk and can't get that last part to work.

NOTE: I do not want to use something like `grep -v "$last_name,$first_name"`; I want to use a filtering function.

Comment: If you want to suppress all output if the requested name is not found, you'll have to either do two passes over the file, or read the full data into memory so you can decide if to print it or not. But if the idea is to _remove_ matching lines, why do that? The empty output would be impossible to separate from a situation where _all_ lines match. If you want to check if the script removed any lines, have it set an appropriate exit status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect right inside the awk script, and only output matches found.

```
awk -F',' -v last="$last_name" -v first="$first_name" '
  $1==last && $2==first {next}
  {print > "tmpfile"}
' file.csv
```

Here are some differences between your script and this....

- This has awk reading your CSV directly, rather than having [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).
- This actively *skips* the records you want to skip,
- and prints everything else through a redirect.

Note that you could, if you wanted, specify the target to which to redirect in a variable you pass in using `-v` as well.

If you really want the "No match found" error, you can set a flag, then use the `END` special condition in awk...

```
awk -F',' -v last="$last_name" -v first="$first_name" '
  $1==last && $2==first { found=1; next }
  { print > "tmpfile" }
  END { if (!found) print "No match found." > "/dev/stderr" }
' file.csv
```

And if you want no tmpfile to be created if a match wasn't found, you would either need to scan the file TWICE, once to verify that there's a match, and once to print, or if there's no risk that the size of the file would be too great for available memory, you could keep a buffer:

```
awk -F',' -v last="$last_name" -v first="$first_name" '
  $1==last && $2==first { next }
  { output = (output ? output ORS : "" ) $0 }
  END {
    if (output)
      print output > "tmpfile"
    else
      print "No match found." > "/dev/stderr"
  }
' file.csv
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested any of these. :)

Comment: Very thorough response. I was avoiding creating a tmpfile if a match wasn't found because I thought it would be more efficient, but now I realize why I was wrong :)

Comment: It's all a balancing act. When the job is very small, it doesn't matter too much whether you "delete a junk file" or "use some extra memory". It's only in the extreme cases, where you might have to delete a million junk files, or create a buffer bigger than your memory, that this stuff starts to have an impact. It's great that you're thinking about these optimizations early on, before you actually trip over them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do two passes over the file, or you can queue up all of the file so far in memory and then just fail if you reach the END block with no match.

```
awk -v first="$first" last="$last" '$1 != last || $2 != first {
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) print a[i] >>"tempfile"; p=1; split("", a); }
    # No match yet, remember this line for later
    !p { a[++n] = $0; next }
    # If we get through to here, there was a match
    p { print >>"tempfile" }
    END { if (!p) { print "no match" >"/dev/stderr"; exit 1 } }' filename
```

This requires you to have enough memory to store the entire file (this will be required when there is no match).

Answer (score 0):

With a bash script, you can test if awk print something.

If yes, remove the tmpfile.

```
c=$(awk -F',' -v a="$last_name" -v b="$first_name" '
  $1==a && $2==b {c=1;next}
  {print > "tmpfile"}
  END{if (!c){print "no match"}}' infile)
[ -n "$c" ] && { echo "$c"; rm tmpfile;}
```